# Jquery How to display result of minutes in range

Tags: jquery

I have this problem. I want to show the minute range of the result. To make it clear here is an example. Example: if the result from 3 inputs are '20,30,25' respectively, i want to make it into this '0-20,20-50,50-75'. So it will get the result from the first input and add it the result of the next input and there result will be added to the next input and so on but in a range format. Here is my code.

```js
$("#inputs input.time").mask("00:00:00");
$("#inputs input.time").prop('value', '00:00:00');

Number.prototype.padDigit = function() {
  return (this < 10) ? '0' + this : this;
}
$('#display').click(function() {
  $('#show').show();
});
$('#inputs').on('focus', 'input.time', function() {
  $(this).select();
});
var c = 1;
$('#append').click(function() {
  var cnt = $('.cnt').val();
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    c++;
    $('#inputs').append("<div class='inputs' name='" + c + "'><span class='number'>" + c + "</span>.)<input type='text' name='" + c + "' class='time' value='00:00:00' /><button class='remove' name='" + c + "'>X</button></div>");
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '#inputs .remove', function() {
  var nm = $(this).attr('name');
  $('div[name="' + nm + '"]').remove();
  c--;
  resetCount();
});

function resetCount() {
  $('#inputs div.inputs').each(function(i) {
    $('.number', $(this)).text(i + 2);
    $('input', $(this)).attr('name', i + 2);
  });
}
$('#inputs').on('keyup', 'input.time', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  var t1 = '00:00:00';
  var mins = 0;
  var hrs = 0;
  var sec = 0;
  $('#inputs input.time').each(function() {
    t1 = t1.split(':');
    var t2 = $(this).val().split(':');
    //console.log(Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]))
    sec = Number(t1[2]) + Number(t2[2]);
    secmns = Math.floor(parseInt(sec / 60));
    mins = Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]) + secmns;
    minhrs = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
    hrs = Number(t1[0]) + Number(t2[0]) + minhrs;
    sec = sec % 60;
    mins = mins % 60;
    t1 = hrs.padDigit() + ':' + mins.padDigit() + ':' + sec.padDigit()
  });
  if (t1 == 'NaN:NaN:NaN') {
    t1 = '00:00:00';
  }
  $('#total').text(t1);
  /*****************subtract time*****************/
  //new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
  //problem, if the seconds, mins or hrs of total is bigger than the remaining. Unexpected result
  var start = $('#rem').text();
  var end = $('#total').text();
  s = start.split(':');
  e = end.split(':');
  var se = Number(s[2]) - Number(e[2]);
  var sems = Math.floor(parseInt(sec / 60));
  var mi = Number(s[1]) - Number(e[1]) - sems;
  var mihr = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
  var hr = Number(s[0]) - Number(e[0]) - mihr;
  if (se < 0) {
    mi = mi - 1;
    se = se + 60;
  }
  if (mi < 0) {
    hr = hr - 1;
    mi = mi + 60;
  }
  var result = hr.padDigit() + ':' + mi.padDigit() + ':' + se.padDigit();
  if (result == 'NaN:NaN:' + se) {
    result = '00:00:00';
  }
  $('#remain').text(result);
});
$('.save').click(function() {
  var arr = new Array();
  $('#inputs input.time').each(function() {
    var tim = $(this).val().split(':');
    arr.push(tim[1]);
  });
  $('#disp').html('result: ' + arr.join(','));
});
```

```css
#remain,
#total {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#disp {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
input:focus {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
input {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/master/src/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<button id='display'>Display</button>
<div id='disp'></div>
<div id='show'>Remaining:
  <div id='remain'>01:20:30</div>Total:
  <div id='total'>00:00:00</div>
  <div id='rem'>01:20:30</div>
  <br>
  <input type='text' class='cnt' value='1' placeholder="num of append" />
  <button id='append'>+</button>
  <button class="save">Save</button>
  <br>
  <div id='inputs'>1.)
    <input type='text' class='time' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope you can help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for viewing my post. It took me a lot of time to get the result I want. So here is my code as the answer to my own question to give others a reference if they encounter the same problem as I did.

```js
$("#inputs input.time").mask("00:00:00");
$("#inputs input.time").prop('value', '00:00:00');

Number.prototype.padDigit = function() {
  return (this < 10) ? '0' + this : this;
}
$('#display').click(function() {
  $('#show').show();
});
$('#inputs').on('focus', 'input.time', function() {
  $(this).select();
});
var c = 1;
$('#append').click(function() {
  var cnt = $('.cnt').val();
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    c++;
    $('#inputs').append("<div class='inputs' name='" + c + "'><span class='number'>" + c + "</span>.)<input type='text' name='" + c + "' class='time' value='00:00:00' /><button class='remove' name='" + c + "'>X</button></div>");
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '#inputs .remove', function() {
  var nm = $(this).attr('name');
  $('div[name="' + nm + '"]').remove();
  c--;
  resetCount();
});

function resetCount() {
  $('#inputs div.inputs').each(function(i) {
    $('.number', $(this)).text(i + 2);
    $('input', $(this)).attr('name', i + 2);
  });
}
$('#inputs').on('keyup', 'input.time', function(event) {
  //console.log(event);
  var t1 = '00:00:00';
  var mins = 0;
  var hrs = 0;
  var sec = 0;
  $('#inputs input.time').each(function() {
    t1 = t1.split(':');
    var t2 = $(this).val().split(':');
    //console.log(Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]))
    sec = Number(t1[2]) + Number(t2[2]);
    secmns = Math.floor(parseInt(sec / 60));
    mins = Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]) + secmns;
    minhrs = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
    hrs = Number(t1[0]) + Number(t2[0]) + minhrs;
    sec = sec % 60;
    mins = mins % 60;
    t1 = hrs.padDigit() + ':' + mins.padDigit() + ':' + sec.padDigit()
  });
  if (t1 == 'NaN:NaN:NaN') {
    t1 = '00:00:00';
  }
  $('#total').text(t1);
  /*****************subtract time*****************/
  //new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
  //problem, if the seconds, mins or hrs of total is bigger than the remaining. Unexpected result
  var start = $('#rem').text();
  var end = $('#total').text();
  s = start.split(':');
  e = end.split(':');
  var se = Number(s[2]) - Number(e[2]);
  var sems = Math.floor(parseInt(sec / 60));
  var mi = Number(s[1]) - Number(e[1]) - sems;
  var mihr = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
  var hr = Number(s[0]) - Number(e[0]) - mihr;
  if (se < 0) {
    mi = mi - 1;
    se = se + 60;
  }
  if (mi < 0) {
    hr = hr - 1;
    mi = mi + 60;
  }
  var result = hr.padDigit() + ':' + mi.padDigit() + ':' + se.padDigit();
  if (result == 'NaN:NaN:' + se) {
    result = '00:00:00';
  }
  $('#remain').text(result);
});
$('.save').click(function() {
  var arr = new Array();
  $('#inputs input.time').each(function() {
    var tim = $(this).val().split(':');
    var tim2 = Number(tim[1]);
    arr.push(tim2);

  });
  var res = arr.join(',');
  var len = arr.length;
  var test = res.toString();
  var test2 = test.split(',');
  var arr2 = new Array();
  var com2 = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { //compute
    var com = com2 + Number(test2[i]);
    com2 = com;
    var com3 = com2;
    arr2.push(com3);
    //console.log(test2[i]);
  }
  var intime = arr2.join(',');
  var intimestr = intime.toString();
  var thisisit = intime.split(',');
  var len2 = arr2.length;
  var arr3 = new Array();
  var len3 = len2 - 1;
  for (var a = 0; a < len2; a++) {
    if (a == 0) {
      var x2 = '0-' + thisisit[a];
    } else if (a > 0 && a < len3) {
      a = a - 1;
      var a1 = a + 1;
      var x2 = thisisit[a] + '-' + thisisit[a1];
      a = a + 1
    } else {
      a = a - 1;
      var x2 = thisisit[a] + '-end';
      a = a + 1;
    }

    if (tyG == undefined) {
      var tyG = x2;
    } else {
      var tyG = tyG + ',' + x2;
    }
  }
  //console.log(tyG);
  //console.log(arr3.join(','));

  $('#disp').html('result: ' + tyG);
});
```

```css
#remain,
#total {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#disp {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
input:focus {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
input {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/master/src/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<button id='display'>Display</button>
<div id='disp'></div>
<div id='show'>Remaining:
  <div id='remain'>01:20:30</div>Total:
  <div id='total'>00:00:00</div>
  <div id='rem'>01:20:30</div>
  <br>
  <input type='text' class='cnt' value='1' placeholder="num of append" />
  <button id='append'>+</button>
  <button class="save">Save</button>
  <br>
  <div id='inputs'>1.)
    <input type='text' class='time' />
  </div>
</div>
```